# Gradle doesn't include module dependencies when executing `gradle clean assemble<BuildVarian>`

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have a multi module Android project. Some input data for the environment:

```
Android Studio 1.0.1
Gradle 2.2.1 (Gradle Wrapper)
Java 1.7.0_71
Android Gradle Plugin: 1.0.1

compileSdkVersion = 21
buildToolsVersion = '21.1.2'
minSdkVersion = 14
targetSdkVersion = 21
```

When I run the project from Android Studio. The application compiles and executes properly on the device (for all build variants). But when I try to `assemble` the app from the terminal with `./gradlew clean assembleDebug` or any other build variant (I have 4: debug, alpha, beta, release) the build succeeds but when I try to run it the app crashes with a `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` for any of the classes defined in a module project.

I've excluded ProGuard as a suspect because it's run only on the release varian. But the issue is consistent for all builds.

Also I checked that modules don't contain repetitive dependencies.

**EDIT**

One posible Stack trace:

```
9553-9553/my.package.app E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: my.package.app, PID: 9553
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: my.package.module1.Go
        at my.package.app.MyApplication.onCreate(MyApplication.java:59)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1013)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4729)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:174)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1367)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5593)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

As you see class `Go` is part of package `my.package.module1` which is defined in a sub module `:module1` (See build script source).

Part of the gradle build:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies{
        classpath 'com.jakewharton.sdkmanager:gradle-plugin:0.12.+'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android-sdk-manager'
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {

    // ...
    // Compile and tools version

    defaultConfig {
        // Target sdk and so on
        applicationId 'my.package.app'

        // ...
        // Other stuff regarding version

    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }

    buildTypes {

        release { // ... }

        alpha { // ... }

        beta { // ... }

        debug { // ... }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    }
}

dependencies {
    // ...
    // Standatrt dependencies like support lib and others

    compile project(':module1')
    compile project(':module2')
    compile project(':module3')

    // Other moduels
}
```

Comment: provide full information about your error

Comment: What kind of info you need?

Comment: full stacktrace of error, full build.gralde

Comment: Added stack trace and part of build script...

Comment: I've tried to pay around with the code... by commenting stuff that uses classes from one module... and the terminal build still crashes... it seams that gradle isn't packaging the code from all my modules in the final APK.
If it would have been an error then ok... but in the IDE it works fine.

Comment: what about `gradlew clean build`, does it crash, too?

Comment: Yes... it crashes... I usually use assemble<BuildVariant> ... Note, that the builds succeed...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69407/discussion-between-gio-and-serj-lotutovici).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After playing around with the build scripts and comparing the way AS assembles a build with the terminal one I've stumbled into the next differences:

1. When AS cleans the project it also executes `generate<BuildVarian>Sources` and `generate<BuildVarian>TestSources` for all  module projects (this is scheduled in such a way that it's always executed before running the actual assemble command)
2. When running `./gradlew clean assembleDebug` from the terminal it seams that gradle doesn't fetch the exported sub module arrs on time. Could be a bug in Gradle 2.2 (2.2.1) or the Android Gradle Plugin - I don't recall having such issues with previous versions
3. When running `./gradlew clean generateDebugSources generateDebugTestSources assembleDebug` the issue is still in place - May be also related to the bug.

*Temp solution*

Execute the the following commands sequentially:

```
# ./gradlew clean generate<BuildVariant>Sources generate<BuildVariant>TestSources
# ... task output
# ...
# ./gradlew assemble<BuildVariant>
```

This way the output apk is assembled with all module projects

*Longterm solution*

Fired an issue ticket [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=106579&thanks=106579&ts=1421971822)